# Access Violation using GetUserName in VB.NET / Visual Studio 2008

Tags: vb.net

I have searched everywhere I can for a solution to this, and the code listed by others does not seem to work.

**Background:** I want to obtain the user's username using VB (Using Visual Studio 2008).  I've done this in Excel VBA before, but the code used before doesn't work.

I've tried code listed on the MS site here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152970

and slightly varied code found here: http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4409/get-current-username-in-vbnet/

There are two issues with the code on the MS site:

1. Dim lpBuff As String * 25 isn't recognised - it says, end of
   expression expected after 'string', as if '* 25' is not recognised; and,
2. When I remove '* 25', I get an 'access violation' on the line: ret =
   GetUserName(lpBuff, 25)

   ```
   Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
   "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, _
   ByRef nSize As Integer) As Integer

   Public Function ReturnUserName() As String

   ' Dimension variables
   Dim lpBuff As String * 25
   Dim ret As Long, UserName As String

   ret = GetUserName(lpBuff, 25)
   ReturnUserName = Left(lpBuff, InStr(lpBuff, Chr(0)) - 1)
   End Function
   ```

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Steve's answer is correct and most elegant, the following illustrates what you have done incorrectly:

1) Defining a fixed length string

**VBA**

```
 Dim lpBuff As String * 25
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim lpBuff As String 
lpBuff = New String(CChar(" "), 25)
```

2) The return variable should be of type Integer

**VB.NET Function**

```
Public Function ReturnUserName() As String 
   Dim iReturn As Integer 
   Dim userName As String 
   userName = New String(CChar(" "), 50) 
   iReturn = GetUserName(userName, 50) 
   Return userName.Substring(0, userName.IndexOf(Chr(0))) 
End Function
```

Comment: Ron, thank you so much for your explanation.  This is very insightful.  Paul

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use

```
 Environment.UserName
```

The [Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z8te35sa.aspx) class contains numerous properties that map directly to base WinApi calls.
If I am not mistaken, [Username](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx) maps to GetUserName as you can see from this decompiled code

```
public static string UserName
{
    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    get
    {
        new EnvironmentPermission(EnvironmentPermissionAccess.Read, "UserName").Demand();
        StringBuilder lpBuffer = new StringBuilder(0x100);
        int capacity = lpBuffer.Capacity;
        if (Win32Native.GetUserName(lpBuffer, ref capacity))
        {
            return lpBuffer.ToString();
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Steve - thank you so much for your explanation of that.  I am fairly experience with VBA, but new to VB.